# What is Repetition of data access and business code Large Projects?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am studying ASP.NET MVC framwork atm and in the very beginning came across this line:-

*To put all the parts together of a large project can also create the repetition problem of data access
code and business logic in your application*

What repetition is it talking about? I haven't worked on any large projects so can't comprehend.

What I can guess is that it is talking about is **code repetition** but weren't languages like Java and C# developed so that codes could be reused? The whole OOPS concept thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate your project into different layers to reduce the code repetition like data access, business logic etc, see the picture.

[image: see the picture]